# Visualforce PDF styles not applying

Tags: visualforce, css, style, instance

All of a sudden our styles on Visualforce pages are not applying. This is not happening in every org and only seems to be in the CS instances. I was viewing these vf pages today and did not have these issues. No changes were made to the pages since then. Is anyone else experiencing similar issues?

I know this isn't a lot to go off of but this is exactly what is happening. Just trying to see if this is happening to anyone else.

Comment: Has your sandbox gone Winter '24?

Comment: Or have you been moved to Hyperforce, perhaps? Also, how are you defining the styles? As style properties or using CSS?

Comment: @NickCook I checked the instances on Salesforce Trust and it says they don't get updated until the 25th. Also the normal clues like the loading icon still is summer 23.

Comment: @PhilW would this show on Salesforce Trust? I am not sure how to tell if these orgs were migrated. There are no inline styles only CSS at the top. I did some testing and weirdly enough the inline styles will apply but when specified through a CSS class it does not apply.

Comment: Facing the same issue with Scratch orgs and all Sandboxes apart from production. No Hyperforce (as far as I can tell, Assistant tells me that Migration is coming soon) and no Winter Release, just the PDFs not rendering as they did a few days ago. Can't contribute to a solution right now but can confirm it's not an individual topic.

Comment: When I was writing VF pages for PDF generation I found that only inline style attributes would work and CSS did not - though this was back in 2018/2019. It seems that both you and @dschib experienced otherwise initially and now face the issue I originally found when developing the VF pages we have. I suggest you raise a support case.

Comment: There are styling hooks that have to be mentioned as part of the <style> tag, such as header and footer positioning. These things don't work just as any other styling has ceased to work. It really seems like a big malfunction of Flying Saucer. A case has been raised already

Comment: @dschib Are your instances on Summer 23 patch 18? All the SBs and scratch orgs I tested are on that version. My customers production instances are on Summer '23 Patch 17.7 and do not have the issue. I also have a ticket open.

Comment: Yes, Patch 18. What's your Case number? Maybe we can refer to one another to show that this is more than bad development. Support tried to redirect us to Developer Support which doesn't really seem to be the right avenue here

Comment: Case #45191244. I havent even gotten a response so you are getting further than me

Comment: I have a call with them at 130

Comment: Unfortunately another one of my Sandboxes from another Production on Patch 18 does not seem to have the same problems ... fascinating this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an active incident now that looks like it could be related. I'm waiting for the rollback to see if that resolves it.

https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/1171

Update: This is related and the rollback fixes all of my VF pages without any changes on my end.

Update2: Salesforce support reached out and confirmed my issue was related to this current issue. Although the workaround `showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false"` solves the issue this is only a workaround with the current bad patch and once they resolve the issues on their end this will not be required

Update3: We still have customers experiencing this issue on hyperforce instances. Namely USA418 which is on Summer '23 Patch 18.1. Hopefully they will be rolling those back as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to confirm that Production and Scratch Orgs / Sandboxes for us bear  differences with the exact same markup

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" >
        <head>
                <style type="text/css" media="print">
                      @page {
                               @top-center {
                                       content: element(header);
                               }
                               @bottom-left {
                                     content: element(footer);
                               }
                      }
                      div.header {
                               padding: 10px;
                               position: running(header);
                      }
                      div.footer {
                               display: block;
                               padding: 5px;
                               position: running(footer);
                      }
                      .pagenumber:before {
                               content: counter(page);
                      }
                      .pagecount:before {
                               content: counter(pages);
                      }
                        
                      div.content{
                               font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
                      }
                    </style>
              </head>
           <div class="header">
              <div>Account name doesnt matter ----------- and the date is {!TODAY()}</div>
           </div>
           <div class="footer">
                <div>Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
               <p>Actual page body information.</p>
          </div>
</apex:page>
```

This looks different between Scratch Org and Production.

[image: markup rendered on production]
This is what it looks like on Prod.

[image: markup rendered on scratch org]

This is what it looks like on our Scratch Org

This definitely warrants investigation.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I will reference this in my call with support

Comment: If you add applyHtmlTag="false" to you VF page does it work?

Comment: As a matter of fact it does. It's strange that this seems to be functioning differently on different patch versions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false"` apparently makes this work on scratch orgs again. I cannot explain why Salesforce seems to treat the same markup differently on the different orgs currently, but this adjustment also saved the PDF we originally saw this problem with.

`showHeader` has to be added when using `applyHtmlTag` but `applyHtmlTag` is the setting that actually fixes things.

Comment: Thank you! I have this issue on production orgs. Yes - this works. Previously i already have showHeader="false", 
 standardStylesheets="false", applyBodyTag="false" added and issue appears, but adding the applyHtmlTag="false" solved it

Comment: showHeader="false" is the minimum amount of additonal info you have to give when using applyHtmlTag="false", which is why I added this.

Comment: On our own production instance, it did actually also come up today while yesterday my testing still had everything intact. Seems like we got to the latest patch too.

Comment: It sadly doesn't explain though why it all of a sudden stopped working or why it works in some instances. I'm hoping SF can still help out as fixing all of our VF pages will be a large maintenance undertaking

Comment: The active incident you linked does explain it pretty well now. The explanation is not complete (as formatting in general didn't get parsed) but I digress.